# How to check if a date is before 10th of that month in mysql?

Tags: mysql, date

I have a date column :

```
Report_Received 
8/7/2019 11:39
6/18/2019 10:25
```

I want to check if the date falls before 10th of that month of that year.
If yes, need to say True else False under a new column(Complaince_Reporting).

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: That doesn't look much like a date column. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`DAY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_day) function to get the day of the month, but first, because you are not using a MySQL Datetime column or a valid MySQL date format, you need to convert your date using [`STR_TO_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date). Something like this:

```
SELECT ...,
    DAY(STR_TO_DATE(Report_received, '%c/%e/%Y')) < 10 AS Compliance_Reporting
FROM yourtable
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=cfc50b678add7072a6daa8728c260271)

Comment: I don't understand why a correct answer would be downvoted.

Comment: @Nick How do I permanently add that column to my table? Cause later I want to map that column into one of the tables in my destination DB.

Comment: @PraneethReddy which version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: @Nick 8.0 version. Anyways, I got the answer I used Update and Set statement to add a permanent column to my table. Thank you.

Comment: @PraneethReddy I was asking because you can use generated columns instead of having to add a permanent column which needs to be updated. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57719984/add-multicolumn-check-constraint-in-mysql/57720033#57720033) for an example and a link to the manual