# add multicolumn check constraint in MySQL

Tags: mysql

In MySQL(the version is 5.7.27-log) I have three column remain_money , usage_money, frozen_money.

the column type is integer.Is there any way to add constraint:`usage_money + frozen_money = remain_money`?

Comment: Why store a column in table, if it can be computed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't store a value that is computed from other columns in the same table. Instead, use a [generated column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html):

```
ALTER TABLE yourtable
ADD c INT AS (a + b)
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=bd1642bfcd1bcbca74f5b1c033af88cd)